# How to supply DateTime with an abbreviated timezone

Tags: perl, timezone

When I try to create a DateTime object after receiving the following date format:

```
Fri 01 Oct 2010 12:19:54 AM JMT
```

I parse the day,month,year,time, and timezone.

However, creating a DateTime object using an abbreviated timezone does not appear to work.

```
# ... After parsing and converting to epoch...
my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $date_epoch,
                                        time_zone => 'JMT' );
```

I get:

```
Invalid offset: JMT
```

Is there a way to supply DateTime an abbreviated timezone?

If not, what's the best way to convert an abbreviated timezone to a full timezone string (in Perl).

Comment: From http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-TimeZone/lib/DateTime/TimeZone.pm: It is strongly recommended that you do _not_ rely on these names for anything other than display. These names are not official, and many of them are simply the invention of the Olson database maintainers. Moreover, these names are not unique. For example, there is an "EST" at both -0500 and +1000/+1100.

Comment: EST has indeed been a source of confusion for me a couple of times!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [DateTime::TimeZone](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-TimeZone/lib/DateTime/TimeZone.pm):

> It is strongly recommended that you do
>   not rely on these names for anything
>   other than display. These names are
>   not official, and many of them are
>   simply the invention of the Olson
>   database maintainers. Moreover, these
>   names are not unique. For example,
>   there is an "EST" at both -0500 and
>   +1000/+1100.